# VB.NET display datagridview with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I am new to VB.NET, I would like to connect to a local SQL Server. I just can't connect, hope someone will fix my code.

```
Public Class Main_Tr

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=IHOMISSERVER;Initial Catalog=homis;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        connection.Open()
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "column_name")
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "column_name"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Main_Tr_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You have set the Initial catalog value twice in your connection string. Whats the name of the database you wish to connect to? Also you have not specified a db instance, just the server. When i connect to a local db i use `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need :

```
connection.open 
connection.close
```

Now use this :

```
  dim con as new connectionstring='your connection string

  dim cmd as new sqlcommand("Select * from [table name-remove brackets if required]",con)

  dim adapter as new sqldataadapter(cmd)

  Dim table as new datatable

  adapter.fill(table)

  datagridview1.datasource=table
```